# JPEG EOF vs EOI marker

Tags: jpeg, file-format

The [JPEG file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) states that the JPEG EOI (End of Image) marker is given by the final `FF D9`. However I very occasionally come across JPEGs that also have a small amount of data following this EOI (in this example `02 24 ...`):

```
FF D8 FF E1
...
...
FF D9
02 24 02 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 10 00 00 00 00 27 10 00 00 27 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 58 53 21 00 1E 5D 32 00 00 00 00
```

Does the JPEG standard allow for data following the EOI marker or is this additional binary data corruption?

If this is not corruption what information is encoded in these final bytes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JPEG standard only defines a JPEG data stream. That is what goes between the SOI and EOI markets. Anything outside that is outside JPEG.

JPEG does not define a file format so technically there is nothing wrong with having extra data at the begin or the end. However, most decoders will puke if you have extra data before the SOI marker.